# 2d-barcode image generator in Python under Qt4?

Tags: python, qt4, barcode

There is any library that support `2d-barcode` image generator in python ?? i need any help to generate a `2d-barcode` (QR-code) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tak a look at https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode, also if it is not related to Qt4

A library for Qt4 is prison, but it seems to have not the python binding